# Как записать аудиопоток

Tags: android

В маркете есть приложения онлайн-радио, которые позволяют записать проигрываемый поток на телефон (т.е. пользователь включил радио, начала играть его любимая песня он нажал записать началась запись потока в mp3 файл, а когда нажал стоп запись остановилась в итоге у него на телефоне есть записанный кусок аудиопотока в mp3 формате). Как такое реализовать на андроид? Скиньте пожалуйста примеры или подскажите источники где такое реализовано.

Нашел такой код, но он не работает. В логах выдает `10-27 09:34:38.675 6327-11006/ru.test.testapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/some_file.mp3 (Permission denied)` и все. Добавление пермишинов соответствующих не помогло

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadFileAsync().execute("http://cdndl.zaycev.net/126541/6134306/polina_gagarina_-_polina_gagarina_-_obezoruzhena_zaycev.net_%28zaycev.net%29.mp3");
            }
        });
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_file.mp3");
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String progress) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А Вы читаете, что Вам пишут, или ждёте готового решения? Для Андроид 6 и выше для записи на SDCard пермишн нужно не только прописывать в манифесте, но и запрашивать в коде. Поскольку Вы этого не делаете система отказывает в доступе к файлу (Permission denied).

Comment: Я бы хотел посмотреть пример как вообще реализован пример того что мне нужно.. Наверняка в интернете есть примеры

Comment: Как вообще запросить в коде пермишн